# Bubble sort floating point numbers in C

Tags: c, floating-point, bubble-sort

I use bubble sort to `1.00 20.00 3.30 4.50 5.20 6.10 7.80 8.10 9.14 0.67` and i end up with

`0.00 1.00 3.00 4.00 5.00 6.00 7.00 8.00 9.00 20.00`

This is my code

```
main()
{
int i,n = 10,j,value=0;
float median=0;
float a[10] = {1,20,3.3,4.5,5.2,6.1,7.8,8.1,9.14,0.67};
for(i= 0; i< 10; i++) {
    printf("%.2f  ", a[i]);
}
printf("\n\n");
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
    {
        if(a[j]>a[j+1])
        {
            value=a[j+1];
            a[j+1]=a[j];
            a[j]=value;
        }
    }
}
for(i= 0; i< 10; i++) {
    printf("%.2f  ", a[i]);
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and why I am losing all the digits after the decimal point when I am done with the sort.

P.S. I am using an online compiler http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php .

Comment: I'm surprised that it did not just occur to you to think: 'Oh look - the output looks like an integer value printed as a float'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` is an `int` not `float`.

```
int i,n = 10,j,value=0;
```

You get truncated values here in the loop:

```
 value=a[j+1];
 a[j+1]=a[j];
 a[j]=value;
```

Make it `float value=0.0f;`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
int value=0;
```

Change to:

```
float value=0.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `value` as an `int`

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and why I am losing all the digits after the decimal point when I am done with the sort.

You declared `value` as an `int`.  `value=a[j+1];` statement will truncate the value of `a[j+1]` (which is of `float` type) to `int`. Declare `value` as `float`.

```
float value = 0.0f;
```